# When downloading file to client browser Using ASP.Net, It downloads it as a .aspx file with the name of the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I will start saying that i'm a rookie at asp.net and i expect you to roast me hard here...
When i download  a file to my browser using asp.net, it downloads the file with the right data but with the name and the ending of the page (in this case - StoragePage.aspx). tho i wanted it to download as the type of file it is in the database with the name it's stored in the database.

I've done it using this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x221CNS0ly0 and as seen at the end of the video it happens to video maker too.

```
I RECOMMEND WATCHING THE END OF THE VIDEO BEFORE ANSWERING!
```

Here's the code i used to download

```cs
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(gone))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getDocument", cn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
    cn.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dt.Load(reader);
}
string name = dt.Rows[0]["File_Name"].ToString();
byte[] documentBytes = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["File_Content"];
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ContentType = "application/octetstream";
Response.AddHeader("content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; File_Name=" + name));
Response.AddHeader("content-Length", documentBytes.Length.ToString());
Response.BinaryWrite(documentBytes);
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
```

I expected it to download as the file name because of this line:

```cs
Response.AddHeader("content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; File_Name=" + name));
```

Comment: Note: You are acrually not using string.Format at all. Check header syntax here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition Beware the quotes around the file name.

Comment: Could you send me the code i need to put for it to work. i kinda need it for a school project and i'm tight on time... i will read it all and understand later.

Comment: Try `Response.AddHeader("content-Disposition", $"attachment; File_Name=\"{name}\"));`

Comment: I just found out what the problem was. i needed to do it like:
`Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename={name}");`
`Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", documentBytes.Length.ToString());`